# i'm using a php mysql wrapper class like this in given link...but i'm not able connect to the db

Tags: php, mysql, oop

```
class DB
  {

    var $defaultDebug = false;


    var $mtStart;

    var $nbQueries;

    var $lastResult;


    function DB($base, $server, $user, $pass)
    {
      $this->mtStart    = $this->getMicroTime();
      $this->nbQueries  = 0;
      $this->lastResult = NULL;
      mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die('Server connexion not possible.');
      mysql_select_db($base)               or die('Database connexion not possible.');
    }

}
```

this is the db class i'm using. i tried creating a new object from this class like `$db=new DB("dbname","localhost","user","rootwdp");` but i'm always getting error couldn't connect to the database.. What is the problem here. someone can help?

And after this i created four variables in the db class. then i instantiated a new object like $dd->new DB(); and added variables to them like $this->dbname="dbname", $this->server="localhost" etc etc..still it says Warning: Missing argument 1 for DB::DB(), called in D:\www\webroot\oops\test.php on line 4 and defined in D:\www\webroot\oops\db.class.php on line 34

Warning: Missing argument 2 for DB::DB(), called in D:\www\webroot\oops\test.php on line 4 and defined in D:\www\webroot\oops\db.class.php on line 34

Warning: Missing argument 3 for DB::DB(), called in D:\www\webroot\oops\test.php on line 4 and defined in D:\www\webroot\oops\db.class.php on line 34

Warning: Missing argument 4 for DB::DB(), called in D:\www\webroot\oops\test.php on line 4 and defined in D:\www\webroot\oops\db.class.php on line 34

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\www\webroot\oops\db.class.php on line 39
Server connexion not possible.line 34 is the method starting point on my editor. Server connexion not possible. What is the problem? where is the problem

Comment: where are your variables $base, $server, $user, $pass stored? If they are in class user $this->base, $this->server, $this->user, $this->pass

Comment: `die(mysql_error())` may be more useful.

Comment: The class you are using uses `mysql_*` functions that are becoming deprecated. They will be removed from future PHP versions, your code will stop working then. If you write new code, don't use it, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Comment: Why not use PDO or Mysqli?

Comment: i created  four variables in the object, $base="dbname", $server="localhost", $user="root", $pass="rootwdp". then i called the method like $db->DB($base,$server,$user,$pass); still its not connecting..